# wordpress ajax menu - move 'active' css tag from <a> to <li>

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menuitem

need a bit of help with an ajax menu in wordpress.
At the moment, the menu successfuly adds the css class tag 'active' in the current menu item .

I need to move this from `<a>` to the parent `<li>`...

Any ideas?

```
    <?php 

            $section_number = 0;
            $first_social_type = '';


            echo '<ul class="current-nav0" id="main-navigation" >';
            if( !empty( $gdl_menu_node ) ){

                foreach( $gdl_menu_node->childNodes as $menu_item ){

                    $active = ''; 

                    if( $section_number == 0){
                        $active = " active";
                        $first_social_tye = (find_xml_value($menu_item, 'icon-type') == 'light')? ' light':'';
                    }

                    echo '<li><a href="' . $gdl_is_home_url . '#section-n' . $section_number . '" id="nav-section' . $section_number . '" class="anchor' . $active . $gdl_is_home_class . '" >';
                    echo __(find_xml_value($menu_item, 'menu-name'), 'gdl_front_end');
                    echo '</a></li>';

                    $section_number++;

                }
            }


        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
echo '<li><a href="' . $gdl_is_home_url . '#section-n' . $section_number . '" id="nav-section' . $section_number . '" class="anchor' . $active . $gdl_is_home_class . '" >';
```

to:

```
echo '<li  class="' . $active . '"><a href="' . $gdl_is_home_url . '#section-n' . $section_number . '" id="nav-section' . $section_number . '" class="anchor' . $gdl_is_home_class . '" >';
```

Comment: Thanks. I tired this, but for some reason it adds the 'active' class tag to the homepage item, and not the others. It also stays on the homepage menu item, it does not remove when navigating, and does not add to the other menu items when navigating.

Comment: Any ideas if i can do this with jQuery instead? I don't mind leaving the 'active' class tag in the `<a>` and add another class tag in the `<li>` with jquery.